# How to convert float into date and time in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a date column in my dataframe that I want to use at an index in that dataframe. I tried to convert this columns using `pd.to_datetime()` but it did not work.

My columns containing date looks like:

```
0        9.2017
1       10.2017
2       11.2017
3       12.2017
4        1.2018
```

Error that I am getting is:

```
ValueError: time data '9' does not match format '%m.%YYYY' (match)
```

Is that related with formatting or I need to use some other library?

Comment: add `format='%m.%Y'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert the column to string first:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'].astype(str), format='%m.%Y')
```

Comment: oh yes it works  .astype(str) was missing :) thank you .

Comment: glad it helped, please accept the answer if it's ok

Comment: yes sure ..after 7 min :)